# Where should GCM's api.key file be located in the WAR file when deploying application to GAE?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, war, google-cloud-messaging

I am attempting to get my .war file that was previously running on my machine locally with Tomcat 6 up on Google Apps. I created the project in Eclipse and the file structure was a little bit different than [Google's GCM Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html). I think I finally have everything in order except for ONE last portion. I don't know what directory the "api.key" belongs under. The stack trace in my logs on the Google Apps server is the following:

```
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@1ef3ccd{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~[app-name]/1.360213803566389174}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find file /api.key on web resources)
    at [package-name].ApiKeyInitializer.getKey(ApiKeyInitializer.java:56)
    at [package-name].ApiKeyInitializer.contextInitialized(ApiKeyInitializer.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
```

You can view what Google says the directories should look like at [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating). When I followed Google's GCM Demo (the first link up top) it placed the "api.key" file under the WEB-INF/classes directory. I try that in the new Google App Engine structure, and I get the error above. I feel like I'm really close as it's clear my servlet is TRYING to run, but it can't find this file. Does anyone know where to put it so it can find it and I can get this working?

Comment: So I just realized that it seems that when I drop the file into the classes folder in WEB-INF that its deleted on each rebuild. The classes directory is actually invisible in Eclipse, and this is probably why. I have been dropping it in through Windows Explorer manually...

Comment: After following [this page:](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/ant#Defining_the_Class_Path) I still can't get it. I have a build script that puts the api.key in the war/WEB-INF/classes directory, but once on the server I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. In my ApiKeyInitializer.java class, I had this:

```
private static final String PATH = "/api.key";
```

When in fact, it should have been this:

```
private static final String PATH = "api.key";
```

I followed [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/ant#The_Complete_Build_File) for the build file. I noticed that it said `All other files found in src/, such as the META-INF/ directory, are copied verbatim to war/WEB-INF/classes/`. This made me realize that I should put the api.key in my Eclipse src directory, so that when compiled it was placed properly in war/WEB-INF/classes. In addition to that, the path had to be relative to the src directory, which is why I needed to do `String PATH = "api.key"` rather than `String PATH = "/api.key"`.